# How to update mysql data by clicking a button?

Tags: html, mysql

I am currently doing a school course project.It requires us to code out a website.We designed a website which provides online food ordering service to our school community.

I want to know how to change a data in a specific filed in mysql server by just clicking one button.

I designed a user profile page which shows the information of the users. They can see their previous orders by clicking "show orders" button. Then a table which contains the ordering information will be displayed.

I added a button behind each row called "Delivered". I wish that the Ordering_status can be changed from "ordering" to "delivered" when user click the "Delivered" button. I attached my layout page below.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lyfjn9hed1zfjyd/user_profile.png

Could anyone kindly help me with this?

I cannot attach my code here. It will display in a mess manner. Please use the link below
https://www.dropbox.com/s/u1h73lx07hrsr78/profile.php

Thank you!

```
<script>

function myfunction(int id)     
    {   
        $link=mysqli_connect("localhost","f34s25","f34s25","f34s25");
        $a="UPDATE orders SET Ordering_status="delivered" where order_id=id;
        $b=mysqli_query($a);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: To post the code, Please Use stackoverflow code format styling, in ASK question you can find `?` symbol, you can click that to know the format and styling

Comment: I cannot post my codes correctly here. Anyone can help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one easy solution is that you assign a name to the button delivered.like this

```
<input type="submit" value="delivered" name="delivered">
```

and when the user will click this submit button take the value in the php part.and check whether it is clicked or not,like this

```
if(isset($_POST['delivered']))
{
$a="update yourtablename set Ordering_status="deleivered" where name="$name";
$b=mysqli_query($a);
}
```

Comment: I believe your solution works.However the problem for me is that there might be a number of orders appearing. Thus, I need to echo out one button at the end of each order(row) to change the delivery status of each specific order(row). I think I may need to use the primary id in table to decide which to row to change. But I do not know how to implement it.

Comment: u mean u want to change the button.please be more specific about your doubt so that i can help you.

Comment: The fact is that when there is a new order showing, there should be a "delivered" button behind.(you can see the picture through my attached link). Each "delivered" button is to change one delivery status of one row(order). I do not know how to do this. Because there are multiple status which need be changed.

Comment: the above query which i wrote will update only one row the others will remain unaffected.use your unique id in where condition.please let me know if i am not clear at what i am saying.

Comment: i think email will be unique in your case so in update where condition take where email=$email than it will update the row having that particular email only.

Comment: I am trying with javascript like this. I used                        echo "<td><button onclick=myfunction(order_id)>Delivered</button></td>";   //This is to generate the button. However, it does not work.... I am searching online for the answer.

Comment: It does not include the email in this orders table. So that I would use order_id to determine which row to change.